# How to return an input within a def function with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and defining functions!

I'm writing a code and, on it, I'll sometimes ask the same question, this is why I want to use a function for it. I'm trying like this:

```
def cont():
  ans = input("Continue? ")
  return ans
```

But it's not storing anything on ans, cause every time I call it, I get an error saying that ans has not been declared!

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Your issue is in HOW you call this function, by using `return ans` whatever is stored in `ans` will be the output of your function.   To keep that output to use later you need to save it in a variable.  Try these two lines: `abc = cont()`  `print(abc)`

Comment: This works as written without error. Are you trying to reference `ans` outside your function? `ans` is only declared in the functions namespace. You have to set a variable to be the result of `cont`: `any_var = cont()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ans` is only defined inside the scope of your `cont()` function, you cannot access it directly from outside that function.  You are most of the way to sending this `ans` back out to the rest of your code with `return ans`, now you just need to store that value in something you can access from the rest of your code.  Here is a sample code where I saved the output of `cont()` in the variable `check` in each pass of a while loop.

```
def cont():
    ans = input("Continue? ")
    return ans

gonna_continue = True

while gonna_continue:
    check = cont()
    if check == "no":
        gonna_continue = False
print("All Done")
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
Continue? 1
Continue? 2
Continue? 5
Continue? sbdj2
Continue? no
All Done
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your function. Here's an example:

```
def cont():
    ans = input("Continue? ")
    return ans


for i in range(2):
    print(cont())
```

Output:

```
Continue? y
y
Continue? n
n
```

If you need to use it in an `if-statement`:

```
for i in range(3):
    result = cont()
    if result == 'y':
        print('yes')
    elif result == 'n':
        print('no')
    else:
        print("I don't understand")
```

Output:

```
Continue? y
yes
Continue? n
no
Continue? p
I don't understand
```

However, if you don't plan on expanding the `cont()` function, and doing something more complex with it, as it is now, it's pretty useless because you can simply use `input("Continue? ")` wherever you use `cont()`.

Comment: This is a great overview, the only piece I don't see that may be tripping up the OP is assigning the output of the function to a variable for later reference. You might consider adding that.

Comment: @AmirAShabani yeah, I guess I'm thinking to much by trying to use it as a function. IDK. But thanks a lot!!

Comment: @IagoAmbrósio You're welcome. Feel free to accept an answer if your question has been solved.